# Swift fastlane issue CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I am facing the above issue with New Mac M1 with Xcode 13.1.

I am running fastlane and getting this error

** TEST BUILD FAILED **
[21:03:58]: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[21:03:58]: ▸   MergeSwiftModule normal x86_64
[21:03:58]: ▸   CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
[21:03:58]: ▸ (2 failures)

❌  error: merge-module command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Select your project in Xcode, and go to "Build Settings". Scroll down until you see "Search Paths", and finally, "Library Search Paths". Replace "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)" with "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift".

Comment: All i can see in my Paths is